# indicator from tradingview default, and one created from pinescript doesnot match

Tags: pine-script

On 15m chart I tried use 1h cci, but when I tried to replicate the same indictor with the same setting, results are not the same.
[image: 15m chart]

PineScript
[image: PineScript]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to calculate `CCI` into `security()` scope, not `ohlc` values:

```
//@version=4
study(title="Commodity Channel Index", shorttitle="CCI", format=format.price, precision=2, resolution="")

re = input("60", type = input.resolution)

length = input(20, minval=1)
src = input(hlc3, title="Source")
ma = sma(src, length)

cci =  security(syminfo.ticker, re, (src - ma) / (0.015 * dev(src, length)))

plot(cci, "CCI", color=#2962FF)
band1 = hline(100, "Upper Band", color=#787B86, linestyle=hline.style_dashed)
band0 = hline(-100, "Lower Band", color=#787B86, linestyle=hline.style_dashed)
fill(band1, band0, color=color.rgb(33, 150, 243, 90), title="Background")
```

Comment: thank you for your replay

Answer (score 0):

with thanks to Starr Luck, this is what I ended up to:

```
study("CCi",overlay = false)

length = input(20, minval=1)
src = input(hlc3, title="Source")
ma = sma(src, length)
cci=security(syminfo.tickerid,"60", (src - ma) / (0.015 * dev(src, length)), barmerge.gaps_on, barmerge.lookahead_off )

plot(cci, "CCI", color=#2962FF)
band1 = hline(100, "Upper Band", color=#787B86, linestyle=hline.style_dashed)
band0 = hline(-100, "Lower Band", color=#787B86, linestyle=hline.style_dashed)
fill(band1, band0, color=color.rgb(33, 150, 243, 90), title="Background")
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).